# Grub rescue : how to fix insmod normal, unknown file system

Tags: linux, windows, ubuntu, boot, grub

I have  dual boot with Linux and Windows on my machine, So apparently after I made a new disk partition, I think I messed up the  Linux partition. Now after I boot my machine I get the grub rescue console.
I tried to fix this with these commands  :

Set boot =(hd0, 6)

Set prefix=(hd0,6)/boot /grub

This Commands run fine but when I type :

Insmod normal

I get unknown file system  error

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't know much about grab, But this is what I get when I type ls : (hd0)  (hd0, msdos6)  (hd0, msdos6)  (hs0, msdos5)  (hd0, msdos3)  (hd0, msdos2)  (hd0, msdos1) . furthermore when I try to ls into every partition, I get Filesystem is unknown.  Anyway I will try to do your option by booting with Ubuntu fix grub from there. Hope this works, thank you.

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows has a relatively easy solution. Please remember that when you boot from a CD you can (yes, you can) install applications, but they are (generally) not stored. When you reboot, they are gone too, but this doesn't change anything in your case. http://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows has a much more detailed description, but it is easy to mess something up... Hope this helps.

Comment: (hd0) means the first hard drive, since you don't get any other entries like (hd1) and above, one can tell that you have one hard drive in your computer. The partition numbering starts at 1 (not 0), so (hd0,1) (or (hd0,msdos1)) is the first partition, then (hd0,2), (hd0,3), then your extended partition is most likely the (hd0,4), and the logical drives inside the partition are (hd0,5) and (hd0,6). Also keep in mind that you most likely have a swap partition for linux. Just boot from a CD and open disks utility and it will show you what's where...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you please provide more details.
Like the partition table, how comfortable you are with Grub, etc.

You may want to set `root` (not `boot`) to (hd0, x)

x being 6 implies it's the second logical disk in the extended partition on your hard drive, is this correct?

If you have a chance, burn a CD/make bootable USB (faster!) and boot Ubuntu or Mint from it (or your favourite distro of Linux), then you can `chroot` into your hard drive's linux partition and fix Grub from there. It will rebuild Grub as if you were currently running Linux off that hard drive.

Without more details, it's hard to give you more pointers.

Hope this sheds some light on your problem.